# Proving $a^4+b^4=c^2$ has no nontrivial integer solution

Tags: number-theory

The following is taken from *Numbers and Geometry* by John Stillwell 4.7 exercise 1.

I don't understand why $(c+b^2)(c-b^2)=a^4 \implies c+b^2=8u^4, c-b^2=2v^4$ or $c+b^2=2u^4, c-b^2=8v^4$. I understand that since $a = 2k$, $a^4=16k^4$, but why can't $c+b^2=u^4, c-b^2=16v^4$?

I also don't understand why $(u^2+b)(u^2-b)=4v^2 \implies u^2+b = 2r^2, u^2-b=2s^2$. In fact I am not even sure if the parity of $u$ can be determined.
[image]

Comment: We are breaking up $a^4 = 2^4u^4v^4$ such that $u$ is odd. Since $c+b^2$ is even, it must also have a factor of $2$.

Comment: @SeanIan FYI, regarding proving $a^4+b^4=c^2$ has no non-trivial solutions, I found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E4%2Bb%5E4%3Dc%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainteger&p=1) the questions [Proving $x^4+y^4=z^2$ has no integer solutions](/q/2087679) and [$x^4 + y^4 = z^2$](/q/276515), plus the AoPS threads [#7 equation of integer solutions](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2492032p20983447) and [Number Theory Problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1889479p12887004).

Comment: @Bonnaduck Good point, but it'd be nice if Stillwell had explicitly mentioned that we can choose $u$ to be odd. ;)

Comment: $u$ is odd because $u^4 = b^2+4v^4$ and $b$ is odd.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Nice link, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's spell out some of the reasoning. If $a, b, c$ have no common divisor, then $c$ is odd. Why? Well, clearly, they can't all be even, because then they would have a common factor of $2$. But why can't $a$ and $b$ both be odd and $c$ even? Because the fourth power of an odd number is always equivalent to $1$ modulo $8$; their sum would then be equivalent to $2$ modulo $8$, and that can never be the square of an even number (which is always divisible by $4$).

Since $c$ is odd, $a$ and $b$ are one odd, one even. Say, without loss of generality, that $a$ is even and $b$ is odd. Then if $a = 2k$ for some integer $k$, then $a^4 = 16k^4$. So then the claim is that we can factor $c^2-b^4$ into $(c+b^2)(c-b^2)$, and one of them must be twice a fourth power and the other must be $8$ times a fourth power. Why?

Why couldn't they both be $4$ times a fourth power? Because $b$ is odd, and $(c+b^2)-(c-b^2) = 2b^2$. Twice an odd square is always equivalent to $2$ modulo $4$, meaning that $c+b^2$ and $c-b^2$ can't both be divisible by $4$.

Why couldn't one be $16$ times a fourth power and the other be any fourth power? Because the former would clearly be equal to $0$ modulo $8$, and the latter would also be equal to $0$ modulo $8$ (being even), and again their difference could not be twice an odd square.

---

Notice that $c+b^2$ and $c-b^2$ also cannot have any other common factors other than $2$. Why? Because then their sum $2c$ and their difference $2b^2$ would also have that common factor, which means that $c$ and $b$ would have a common factor, which they don't, by hypothesis.

---

A similar line of reasoning applies to $u^4-b^2 = (u^2+b)(u^2-b)$. The argument is that both factors must be $2$ times a fourth power. Why couldn't one be $4$ times a fourth power and the other any fourth power? If the latter is odd, then their difference is odd; if the latter is even, then their difference is divisible by $4$. Neither can be twice an odd number ($2b$).

---

Finally, $u$ is odd because $u^4 = b^2+4v^4$, and $b$ is odd. But $u$ and $b$ cannot have any common factors, because then $c = u^4-b^2$ would also have that factor in common with $b$, which again, they don't, by hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the author left a lot of subtle details unfilled...

Comment: @SeanIan: Maybe. There might be a more direct line of reasoning for these. Not an expert by any means! :-)